# Numeric values from transform

Tags: numerical-value

How would I create a table of values from a transformation? eg:

```
r1 = 1; r2 = 1000; primorial[n_] := Times @@ Prime[Range[n]];
plot = ListLinePlot[Table[N[Log[primorial[n]]], {n, r1, r2}]];
plot /. L_Line :> {GeometricTransformation[L, ReflectionTransform[{-1, 1}]]}
```

How could I convert the transform of 'plot' into a list of numeric values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you  are after?

```
Cases[ plot, Line[x_] :> ReflectionTransform[{-1, 1}] /@ x, ∞]


% // Line // Graphics
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! Thank you :)